# Telerik RadSideDrawer crash on Android 4.4

Tags: android, angular, crash, telerik, nativescript

There seems to be a problem with the Telerik SideDrawer only on *Android 4.4.2* (or just 4.4, which is the minimum version TNS supports). I've reported it on the repository issues section, but got no answers yet (https://github.com/telerik/nativescript-ui-feedback/issues/388).

Maybe someone here can help me with a workaround. I've tried a few things, but couldn't get it fixed.

There's a demo sample attached below, but we have similar issues on production apps, and Android 4.4 devices are still widely used around here, so this is a problem.

- **Progress NativeScript UI version:** 3.1.4
- **CLI:** 3.2.1
- **Cross-platform modules:** 3.2.0
- **Runtime(s):** 3.2.0

#### Please tell us how to recreate the issue in as much detail as possible.

1. Start the *'crashtestdummy'* app on Android 4.4.2.
2. Minimize it (tap the 'Home' button).
3. Open some other app (this step is not mandatory).
4. Open the currently running apps list (that is: hold the home button, or use the dedicated button to show the list of apps currently running in the device).
5. Select the *'crashtestdummy'* app.
6. It should crash as you can see on the screenshots.

I think this component should work fine on Android 4.4, as it's the minimum version TNS supports.

#### Is there code involved? If so, please share the minimal a recreate the problem.

I've attached a demo project 'crash test dummy.zip', it's just the base NS Angular template + nativescript-pro-ui + a simple SideDrawer implementation.

- I couldn't reproduce the problem on an Android 4.4.2 emulator, only on physical devices.
- I tried updating to the 3.3.0 CLI, runtime and tns-core-modules but the problem persists.

[crash test dummy.zip](https://github.com/telerik/nativescript-ui-feedback/files/1451095/crash.test.dummy.zip)

---

1. Open the app.

[image]

2. Check everything's fine.

[image]

3. Minimize the app, and the you can switch to another one (or not). Open the running apps list, and select your app again.

[image]

4. Crash.

[image]

5. Device info.

[image]

---

**Exception thrown on device:**

```
An uncaught Exception occurred on "main" thread.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.crashtestdummy.test/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity}: com.tns.NativeScriptException: 
Calling js method onCreate failed

Error: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.AbsListView$SavedState cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean
    com.telerik.android.primitives.widget.sidedrawer.SideDrawerState.<init>(SideDrawerState.java:71)
    com.telerik.android.primitives.widget.sidedrawer.SideDrawerState$1.createFromParcel(SideDrawerState.java:11)
    com.telerik.android.primitives.widget.sidedrawer.SideDrawerState$1.createFromParcel(SideDrawerState.java:8)
    android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2107)
    android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2016)
    android.os.Parcel.readSparseArrayInternal(Parcel.java:2374)
    android.os.Parcel.readSparseArray(Parcel.java:1738)
    android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2073)
    android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2317)
    android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:249)
    android.os.Bundle.getSparseParcelableArray(Bundle.java:1273)
    android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:827)
    android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
    android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1044)
    android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchCreate(FragmentManager.java:1848)
    android.app.Activity.onCreate(Activity.java:902)
    com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method)
    com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:1084)
    com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:966)
    com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:953)
    com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:937)
    com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:929)
    com.tns.NativeScriptActivity.onCreate(NativeScriptActivity.java:13)
    android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5264)
    android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
    android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2302)
    android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
    android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
    android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
    android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
    android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:641)
    dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
File: "file:///data/data/com.crashtestdummy.test/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/frame.js, line: 584, column: 18

StackTrace: 
    Frame: function:'ActivityCallbacksImplementation.onCreate', file:'file:///data/data/com.crashtestdummy.test/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/frame.js', line: 584, column: 19
    Frame: function:'NativeScriptActivity.onCreate', file:'file:///data/data/com.crashtestdummy.test/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/activity.js', line: 20, column: 25


    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2338)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:641)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: com.tns.NativeScriptException: 
Calling js method onCreate failed

Error: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.AbsListView$SavedState cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean
    com.telerik.android.primitives.widget.sidedrawer.SideDrawerState.<init>(SideDrawerState.java:71)
    com.telerik.android.primitives.widget.sidedrawer.SideDrawerState$1.createFromParcel(SideDrawerState.java:11)
    com.telerik.android.primitives.widget.sidedrawer.SideDrawerState$1.createFromParcel(SideDrawerState.java:8)
    android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2107)
    android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2016)
    android.os.Parcel.readSparseArrayInternal(Parcel.java:2374)
    android.os.Parcel.readSparseArray(Parcel.java:1738)
    android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2073)
    android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2317)
    android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:249)
    android.os.Bundle.getSparseParcelableArray(Bundle.java:1273)
    android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:827)
    android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
    android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1044)
    android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchCreate(FragmentManager.java:1848)
    android.app.Activity.onCreate(Activity.java:902)
    com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method)
    com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:1084)
    com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:966)
    com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:953)
    com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:937)
    com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:929)
    com.tns.NativeScriptActivity.onCreate(NativeScriptActivity.java:13)
    android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5264)
    android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
    android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2302)
    android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
    android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
    android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
    android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
    android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:641)
    dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
File: "file:///data/data/com.crashtestdummy.test/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/frame.js, line: 584, column: 18

StackTrace: 
    Frame: function:'ActivityCallbacksImplementation.onCreate', file:'file:///data/data/com.crashtestdummy.test/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/frame.js', line: 584, column: 19
    Frame: function:'NativeScriptActivity.onCreate', file:'file:///data/data/com.crashtestdummy.test/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/activity.js', line: 20, column: 25


    at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method)
    at com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:1084)
    at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:966)
    at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:953)
    at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:937)
    at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:929)
    at com.tns.NativeScriptActivity.onCreate(NativeScriptActivity.java:13)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5264)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2302)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.AbsListView$SavedState cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean
    at com.telerik.android.primitives.widget.sidedrawer.SideDrawerState.<init>(SideDrawerState.java:71)
    at com.telerik.android.primitives.widget.sidedrawer.SideDrawerState$1.createFromParcel(SideDrawerState.java:11)
    at com.telerik.android.primitives.widget.sidedrawer.SideDrawerState$1.createFromParcel(SideDrawerState.java:8)
    at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2107)
    at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2016)
    at android.os.Parcel.readSparseArrayInternal(Parcel.java:2374)
    at android.os.Parcel.readSparseArray(Parcel.java:1738)
    at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2073)
    at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2317)
    at android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:249)
    at android.os.Bundle.getSparseParcelableArray(Bundle.java:1273)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:827)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1044)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchCreate(FragmentManager.java:1848)
    at android.app.Activity.onCreate(Activity.java:902)
    ... 21 more
```

---

**Logcat**

```
V/ActivityThread(19641): Performing resume of ActivityRecord{421189c0 token=android.os.BinderProxy@42118078 {com.crashtestdummy.test/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity}} finished=false
D/ActivityThread(19641): ACT-AM_ON_RESUME_CALLED ActivityRecord{421189c0 token=android.os.BinderProxy@42118078 {com.crashtestdummy.test/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity}}
V/ActivityThread(19641): Resume ActivityRecord{421189c0 token=android.os.BinderProxy@42118078 {com.crashtestdummy.test/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity}} started activity: false, hideForNow: false, finished: false
V/ActivityThread(19641): Resuming ActivityRecord{421189c0 token=android.os.BinderProxy@42118078 {com.crashtestdummy.test/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity}} with isForward=true
V/ActivityThread(19641): Scheduling idle handler for ActivityRecord{421189c0 token=android.os.BinderProxy@42118078 {com.crashtestdummy.test/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity}}
D/ActivityThread(19641): ACT-LAUNCH_ACTIVITY handled : 0 / ActivityRecord{421189c0 token=android.os.BinderProxy@42118078 {com.crashtestdummy.test/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity}}
D/ActivityThread(19641): ACT-AM_ON_PAUSE_CALLED ActivityRecord{421189c0 token=android.os.BinderProxy@42118078 {com.crashtestdummy.test/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity}}
D/ActivityThread(19641): ACT-PAUSE_ACTIVITY handled : 0 / android.os.BinderProxy@42118078
V/ActivityThread(19641): Finishing stop of ActivityRecord{421189c0 token=android.os.BinderProxy@42118078 {com.crashtestdummy.test/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity}}: show=true win=com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow@4229e1c8
D/ActivityThread(19641): ACT-STOP_ACTIVITY_SHOW handled : 0 / android.os.BinderProxy@42118078
V/ActivityThread(19641): Performing resume of ActivityRecord{421189c0 token=android.os.BinderProxy@42118078 {com.crashtestdummy.test/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity}} finished=false
D/ActivityThread(19641): ACT-AM_ON_RESUME_CALLED ActivityRecord{421189c0 token=android.os.BinderProxy@42118078 {com.crashtestdummy.test/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity}}
V/ActivityThread(19641): Resume ActivityRecord{421189c0 token=android.os.BinderProxy@42118078 {com.crashtestdummy.test/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity}} started activity: false, hideForNow: false, finished: false
V/ActivityThread(19641): Resuming ActivityRecord{421189c0 token=android.os.BinderProxy@42118078 {com.crashtestdummy.test/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity}} with isForward=true
V/ActivityThread(19641): Scheduling idle handler for ActivityRecord{421189c0 token=android.os.BinderProxy@42118078 {com.crashtestdummy.test/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity}}
D/ActivityThread(19641): ACT-RESUME_ACTIVITY handled : 1 / android.os.BinderProxy@42118078
D/ActivityThread(19641): ACT-AM_ON_PAUSE_CALLED ActivityRecord{421189c0 token=android.os.BinderProxy@42118078 {com.crashtestdummy.test/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity}}
D/ActivityThread(19641): ACT-PAUSE_ACTIVITY handled : 1 / android.os.BinderProxy@42118078
D/dalvikvm(19641): create interp thread : stack size=128KB
D/dalvikvm(19641): create new thread
D/dalvikvm(19641): new thread created
D/dalvikvm(19641): update thread list
D/dalvikvm(19641): threadid=19: interp stack at 0x588fc000
D/dalvikvm(19641): init ref table
D/dalvikvm(19641): init mutex
D/dalvikvm(19641): threadid=19: created from interp
D/dalvikvm(19641): start new thread
D/dalvikvm(19641): threadid=19: notify debugger
D/dalvikvm(19641): threadid=19 (AsyncTask #4): calling run()
V/ActivityThread(19641): Finishing stop of ActivityRecord{421189c0 token=android.os.BinderProxy@42118078 {com.crashtestdummy.test/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity}}: show=false win=com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow@4229e1c8
V/PhoneWindow(19641): DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 4 ,Parent =ViewRoot{4230e350 com.crashtestdummy.test/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity,ident = 0}, this =com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{421e0e08 I.E..... R....... 0,0-480,800}
D/ActivityThread(19641): ACT-STOP_ACTIVITY_HIDE handled : 0 / android.os.BinderProxy@42118078
D/OpenGLRenderer(19641): Flushing caches (mode 1)
D/dalvikvm(19641): threadid=18: bye!
D/OpenGLRenderer(19641): Flushing caches (mode 0)
D/ActivityThread(19641): ACT-DESTROY_ACTIVITY handled : 0 / android.os.BinderProxy@42118078
I/Choreographer(19641): Skipped 824 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
V/ActivityThread(19641): ActivityRecord{421281c0 token=android.os.BinderProxy@42118078 {com.crashtestdummy.test/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity}}: app=com.tns.NativeScriptApplication@4211e320, appName=com.crashtestdummy.test, pkg=com.crashtestdummy.test, comp={com.crashtestdummy.test/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity}, dir=/data/app/com.crashtestdummy.test-1.apk
D/AndroidRuntime(19641): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm(19641): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41b4ece0)
W/dalvikvm(19641): threadid=1: uncaught exception occurred
W/System.err(19641): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.crashtestdummy.test/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity}: com.tns.NativeScriptException: 
W/System.err(19641): Calling js method onCreate failed
W/System.err(19641): Error: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.AbsListView$SavedState cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean
W/System.err(19641):     com.telerik.android.primitives.widget.sidedrawer.SideDrawerState.<init>(SideDrawerState.java:71)
W/System.err(19641):     com.telerik.android.primitives.widget.sidedrawer.SideDrawerState$1.createFromParcel(SideDrawerState.java:11)
W/System.err(19641):     com.telerik.android.primitives.widget.sidedrawer.SideDrawerState$1.createFromParcel(SideDrawerState.java:8)
W/System.err(19641):     android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2107)
W/System.err(19641):     android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2016)
W/System.err(19641):     android.os.Parcel.readSparseArrayInternal(Parcel.java:2374)
W/System.err(19641):     android.os.Parcel.readSparseArray(Parcel.java:1738)
W/System.err(19641):     android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2073)
W/System.err(19641):     android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2317)
W/System.err(19641):     android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:249)
W/System.err(19641):     android.os.Bundle.getSparseParcelableArray(Bundle.java:1273)
W/System.err(19641):     android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:827)
W/System.err(19641):     android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
W/System.err(19641):     android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1044)
W/System.err(19641):     android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchCreate(FragmentManager.java:1848)
W/System.err(19641):     android.app.Activity.onCreate(Activity.java:902)
W/System.err(19641):     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method)
W/System.err(19641):     com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:1084)
W/System.err(19641):     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:966)
W/System.err(19641):     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:953)
W/System.err(19641):     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:937)
W/System.err(19641):     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:929)
W/System.err(19641):     com.tns.NativeScriptActivity.onCreate(NativeScriptActivity.java:13)
W/System.err(19641):     android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5264)
W/System.err(19641):     android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
W/System.err(19641):     android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2302)
W/System.err(19641):     android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
W/System.err(19641):     android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
W/System.err(19641):     android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
W/System.err(19641):     android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
W/System.err(19641):     android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
W/System.err(19641):     android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
W/System.err(19641):     java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
W/System.err(19641):     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
W/System.err(19641):     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
W/System.err(19641):     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:641)
W/System.err(19641):     dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
W/System.err(19641): File: "file:///data/data/com.crashtestdummy.test/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/frame.js, line: 584, column: 18
W/System.err(19641): StackTrace: 
W/System.err(19641):    Frame: function:'ActivityCallbacksImplementation.onCreate', file:'file:///data/data/com.crashtestdummy.test/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/frame.js', line: 584, column: 19
W/System.err(19641):    Frame: function:'NativeScriptActivity.onCreate', file:'file:///data/data/com.crashtestdummy.test/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/activity.js', line: 20, column: 25
W/System.err(19641):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2338)
W/System.err(19641):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
W/System.err(19641):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
W/System.err(19641):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
W/System.err(19641):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
W/System.err(19641):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
W/System.err(19641):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
W/System.err(19641):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
W/System.err(19641):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
W/System.err(19641):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
W/System.err(19641):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:641)
W/System.err(19641):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
W/System.err(19641): Caused by: com.tns.NativeScriptException: 
W/System.err(19641): Calling js method onCreate failed
W/System.err(19641): Error: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.AbsListView$SavedState cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean
W/System.err(19641):     com.telerik.android.primitives.widget.sidedrawer.SideDrawerState.<init>(SideDrawerState.java:71)
W/System.err(19641):     com.telerik.android.primitives.widget.sidedrawer.SideDrawerState$1.createFromParcel(SideDrawerState.java:11)
W/System.err(19641):     com.telerik.android.primitives.widget.sidedrawer.SideDrawerState$1.createFromParcel(SideDrawerState.java:8)
W/System.err(19641):     android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2107)
W/System.err(19641):     android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2016)
W/System.err(19641):     android.os.Parcel.readSparseArrayInternal(Parcel.java:2374)
W/System.err(19641):     android.os.Parcel.readSparseArray(Parcel.java:1738)
W/System.err(19641):     android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2073)
W/System.err(19641):     android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2317)
W/System.err(19641):     android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:249)
W/System.err(19641):     android.os.Bundle.getSparseParcelableArray(Bundle.java:1273)
W/System.err(19641):     android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:827)
W/System.err(19641):     android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
W/System.err(19641):     android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1044)
W/System.err(19641):     android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchCreate(FragmentManager.java:1848)
W/System.err(19641):     android.app.Activity.onCreate(Activity.java:902)
W/System.err(19641):     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method)
W/System.err(19641):     com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:1084)
W/System.err(19641):     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:966)
W/System.err(19641):     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:953)
W/System.err(19641):     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:937)
W/System.err(19641):     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:929)
W/System.err(19641):     com.tns.NativeScriptActivity.onCreate(Na
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested, the issue was fixed here https://github.com/telerik/nativescript-ui-feedback/issues/388#issuecomment-343208902